# simple Java Regex read between two

Tags: java, regex

So I have a source page in text and I know it contains a link that is formatted like this

img src="http://someurl   and ends with -t1

I am trying to extract whatever is between img src and -t1 . It doesn't have to be perfect . I  can work with "http... or src="http... or so on . I just want to trim the source code to around that URL . I am reading about Regex but just can't seem to figure the logic . Anyone Can help ?

```
    File workfile = new File("page.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(workfile));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //System.out.println(line);

        //Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src"+"t1");  ???
        //Matcher m = p.matcher("t1");              ???

    }
    br.close();
```

Edit : Solved by Using :

```
String url = line.split("<img src=")[1].split("-t1")[0];    
System.out.println(url);
```

Thanks goes to all reply's .

Comment: THis seems to be HTML, so why don't you use an HTML parser?

Comment: testing ... Don't know about HTML parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String url = <your url eg... img src='http://someurl and ends with -t1'>

String whatYouWant = url.split("img src")[1].split("-t1")[0];
```

`whatYouWant` is the required string by you

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("img src(.+?)-t1");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("img src=\"http://someurl-t1");
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // Prints String I want to extract
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your urls are similar to your example you can do some thing like this.

```
    String src="img src=\"http://someurl and ends with -t1\"";
    String[] url=src.split("img src");
    String[] str=url[1].split("-t1");
    System.out.println(str[0]);
```

Comment: no they are each different but all start and finish with those signs