# Reading a specific text in Java

Tags: java, file-io

This is kind of a followup to my other question [simple Java Regex read between two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692641/simple-java-regex-read-between-two)

Now my code looks like this. I am reading the contents of a file, scanning for whatever between src and -t1. Running this code will return 1 correct link but the source file contains 10 and I can't figure out the loop. I thought another way might be to write to a second file on disk and remove the first link from the original source but I can't code that either:

```
File workfile = new File("page.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(workfile));
String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //System.out.println(line);


    String url = line.split("<img src=")[1].split("-t1")[0];    
    System.out.println(url);

  }
  br.close();
```

Comment: Can you please show us your input file, and your expected output?

Comment: I deleted my answer (which had problems, sure), because using `split()` this way is ... wrong, and I don't want to support it further.

Comment: @ steve : hmm  ... maybe . @ paul . Tnx anyway . I am open to other suggestion as long as it gets the job done :)

Comment: @anno, maybe you'll post a sample input file and expected output?  It's not our problem...

Comment: @ Steve : I posted enough info to get my answer within 20 min and as for the source code its 142kb (big) and I like to keep that private . So don't go attacking me or voting me down Just because you can't work with my info . I don't mean you parse but this seems to be the culture around here especially toward newcomers. I apologize If I offended you but just had to get that off my chest . cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
import java.util.regex.*;

Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile("<img src=(.*?)-t1");

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher m = urlPattern.matcher (line);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
}
```

The regular expression looks for strings beginning with `<img src=` and ending with `-t1` (and looks for the shortest substrings possible, so that more than one can be found in the line).  The part in parentheses is a "capture group" to capture the text that gets matched;  this is called group 1.  Then, for each line, we loop on find() to find all occurrences in each line.  Each time we find one, we print what's in group 1.

Comment: returns empty . It finishes the code because I added at end System.out.println ("All Done ! ");

Comment: What do you mean "returns empty"?  Are you saying that the inner loop never prints anything out (i.e. m.find() is always false), or do you mean something else?

Comment: sorry sorry my bad I hadn't remove my while and added yours too . It works Perfectly :)